# Commands that don't require prefixes not working. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been coding a Discord bot using js for a couple days now and most everything has been working fine. I am trying to get my bot to respond to a code word but the command isn't working unless I use my prefix which is !.

I've tried pretty much every variation of the code, but none is working.
Example of the command:

```
if(message.content.includes('ping')) {
    message.reply('Pong');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't know what is causing this error unless you show us more of your code, this tiny snippet won't do.

Answer (score 0):

if your code looks like

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
let token = "your token here";
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.includes('ping')) {
        message.reply('Pong');
    } 
});
client.login(token)
```

and nothing happens when you send 'ping', then it looks like some technical issue. Otherwise, you have to send the whole code so people can take a look and tell you what is wrong.